# Add data labels to vega-lite bar chart

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I have a rather simple bar chart, created with the Python altair library, based on a Pandas DataFrame.

[image: Bar chart]

The code to generate the chart is:

```
Chart(df).configure(background='white').mark_bar().encode(
    X('user_id', bin=Bin(maxbins=10), title='Subscriber count'),
    Y('count(*)', title='Number of publications')
)
```

Which translates to the following vega-lite syntax:

```
{
    "encoding":
    {
        "x":
        {
            "bin":
            {
                "maxbins": 10
            },            "field": "user_id",
            "title": "Subscriber count",
            "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y":
        {
            "aggregate": "count",
            "field": "*",
            "title": "Number of publications"
        }
    },
    "mark": "bar"
}
```

The only thing I'd like to add, are the actual values in (or on) each bar, preferably rotated 90° counter-clockwise.

So far, I've only been able to find the `mark_text` feature, which might be an option if I used layering, but I can't find how to rotate the text. Of course, if there's a better way (or if it's not possible at all), do tell! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text config](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html#text-config) to rotate by a specified angle. Essentially, you may want to do something like: `mark_text(angle=-90, dx=10)`.

Answer (score 0):

[This example from the docs gallery](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html) shows how to add text to bars:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.wheat()

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='wheat:Q',
    y="year:O"
)

text = bars.mark_text(
    align='left',
    baseline='middle',
    dx=3  # Nudges text to right so it doesn't appear on top of the bar
).encode(
    text='wheat:Q'
)

(bars + text).properties(height=900)
```